# Angular 2 join the array of objects using object's name

Tags: angular

In my backend, I will return following response:

```
[
      {
      "id": 1,
      "restaurant_name": "Ajisen Ramen Toronto",
      "description": "Japanese Restaurant",
      "phone": "416-977-8080",
      "address":       {
         "id": 3,
         "address": "332 Spadina Ave",
         "postalCode": "M5T 2G2",
         "latitude": 43.65406,
         "longitude": -79.3989,
         "city": {"city_name": "Toronto"}
      },
      "category":       [
                  {
            "id": 1,
            "categoryName": "Asian"
         },
                  {
            "id": 2,
            "categoryName": "Japanese"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Now in my angular 2 front end, I can successfully access the id, restaurant_name, address, but not the category by following code in

**restaurant.component.html**

```html
<h3 style="color:green">Restaurant List:</h3>
<a *ngFor="let rest of restaurants" class="col-1-4">
  <div>
    <h4>Id: {{rest.id}} - Name: {{rest.restaurant_name}} - Category: {{ rest.category }} - Address: {{rest.address.address}},
      {{rest.address.city.city_name}}</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

I want my Category part display like 'Category: Asian, Japanese', How can I do that?

Here is the **restaurant.ts** class

```ts
import { Address } from './address';
import { Category } from '../category';

export class Restaurant {
 categoryNames : string;
  constructor(public id: number,
    public restaurant_name: String,
    public description: String,
    public phone: String,
    public address: Address,
    public category: Category[]) {
      this.categoryNames = this.category.map(c => c.categoryName).join(',');
  };
}
```

I try access categoryNames in restaurant.component.html, but it didn't return any information to me.

Here is the category.ts

```ts
export class Category {
  constructor(public id: number,
              public categoryName: String) {
  }
}
```

For the rest of the code please refer to https://github.com/zhengye1/Eatr/tree/dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my component I wrote below code and it works fine

```
     constructor(){
      let res = JSON.parse(`[
      {
      "id": 1,
      "restaurant_name": "Ajisen Ramen Toronto",
      "description": "Japanese Restaurant",
      "phone": "416-977-8080",
      "address":       {
         "id": 3,
         "address": "332 Spadina Ave",
         "postalCode": "M5T 2G2",
         "latitude": 43.65406,
         "longitude": -79.3989,
         "city": {"city_name": "Toronto"}
      },
      "category":       [
                  {
            "id": 1,
            "categoryName": "Asian"
         },
                  {
            "id": 2,
            "categoryName": "Japanese"
         }
      ]
   }
]`);
        res = res.map((res1) => {
            return new Restaurant(res1.id,
                                    res1.restaurant_name,
                                    res1.description,
                                    res1.phone,
                                    res1.category);
        });
        this.restaurants = res;
}
```

In the html i wrote

```
<h3 style="color:green">Restaurant List:</h3>
<a *ngFor="let rest of restaurants" class="col-1-4">
  <div>
    <h4>Category:{{ rest.categoryNames }}</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Restaurant` class you have done the following:

```ts
this.categoryNames = this.category.map(c => c.categoryName).join(',');
```

so that is why you expect

```ts
{{ rest.categoryNames }} // I assume `category` was a typo
```

to work in template, as it wouldn't be an array, but... when fetching your data, you have actually not cast your incoming data as instances of `Restaurant` objects, you have done the following in your http-request:

```ts
.then(response => response.json() as Restaurant[])
```

this will not make the array to an array of `Restaurant` objects. You need to map the values to you class to truly make it an array of `Restaurant`.

Well, that can be done for example like this (shortened amount of properties):

```ts
getRestaurants(): Promise<Restaurant[]>{
  return this.http.get(this.restaurantUrl)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json().map(x => new Restaurant(x.id, x.category)))
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Now your `Restaurant` objects will have the "new" property `categoryNames` and it will print just fine in template :)

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/9gOzpGU9IxroSy66edmm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In the object the category is an Array type so you have to loop it and then access the property

```
<h3 style="color:green">Restaurant List:</h3>
<a *ngFor="let rest of restaurants" class="col-1-4">
  <div>
    <h4>Id: {{rest.id}} - Name: {{rest.restaurant_name}} - 
       Category: <span *ngFor="let cat of rest.category"> {{ cat.categoryName}}</span> - Address: {{rest.address.address}},
      {{rest.address.city.city_name}}</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

you can also use ng-template or ng-container in place of